# pykafka no handlers could be found for logger for get_simple_consumer

Tags: python-2.7, apache-kafka

I am trying to write python code for monitoring Kafka consumer lag and for this I am using the pykafka library.

```
Default broker_version = 0.9.0
While using get_simple_consumer, 
consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer(consumer_group=consumer_group, auto_start=False,auto_offset_reset=OffsetType.LATEST,consumer_timeout_ms=5000)
```

Always getting `No handlers could be found for logger for get_simple_consumer.`
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but a nuisance message that PyKafka raises when there is no logging handler configured in client code.